# Compile C# console without dll needed

Tags: c#, dll, console, exe

When I compile my C# Console it comes with an dll, if I remove the dll the application doesn't work, and I need it to work with only an .exe and no .dll files.
https://prnt.sc/t1gu4m

Answer (score 9):

1. Right Click your Project
2. Select Publish
3. Deployment Mode: Self-Contained
4. Check the Produce single file option

Et voila, you got a single exe with the required dependencies

Comment: It appears that the exe won't be portable if i use `self-contained`.

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes, or any option that says anything like 'Produce single file'.  Where is that?  I did find Self-contained Deployment Mode, and that UI contains Profile Name, Configuration, Target Framework, Deployment Mode, Target Runtime, and Target Location.  But no Produce Single File.

Comment: @KyleHumfeld There should be "File publish optiions" which you can extend. The checkbox should be there.

Comment: @MauriceLegoland I saw that in a different SO post with a screenshot, but that whole UI block just doesn't exist in my VS for some reason that I can't even guess at.  Pretty frustrating, when it should be easy!  =)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Maurice Legoland's answer. If you're using dotnet cli, run:

```
dotnet publish -p:PublishSingleFile=true --no-self-contained # Other arguments.
```

Only use the `--no-self-contained` flag if you want your executable to be dependent on .NET i.e, it cannot run without the user having .NET's CoreCLR. Otherwise simply set PublishSingleFile to true. You can also use a manifest/configuration file. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#msbuild) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

**Relevant answer for Visual Studio 2022 and NET7**:

1. Go to *Build* -> *Publish selection*.
2. If you have no any *Publish profile*, you will see "Publish. Where are you publishing today" window.

   - Choose desired location.
   - Now you can see *Profile settings* on *Publish* page.
3. Edit profile settings. Set ***File publish options: Produce single file*** (if you do not see such option then you have to change *Target runtime*).